# How can I give values for a newly initialized array right after declaration

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

How can I give values of my new initialized array if I am using a pointer? E.g.

```
int* array = new int[3];  <- I want to give the values {1,2,3} on the same row but not:

array[0] = 5;
array[1] = 3;
array[2] = 4;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a brace enclosed initializer:

```
int* array = new int[3]{1, 2, 3};
```

The usual warning is that you would need to ensure that you call `delete []` on `array`. This is harder to guarantee than apears at first sight. For this and other reasons, it may be a better idea to use an `std::vector<int>`:

```
std::vector<int> v{1,2,3};
```

If you are stuck with an older, pre-C++11 implementation, then you cannot use the brace enclosed initializer syntax. You will have to use a loop at some level (whether your own, or by using some standard or 3rd party library function.)

Comment: This syntax is only available in c++11.

Comment: @Zacrath And C++11 is C++. The question doesn't place any restrictions on using the current standard.

Comment: The enclosed initializer doesn't work for me. It gives me: 'expected `,' or `;' before '{' token '

Comment: OK, so what is the reason for the down-vote? Is there anything wrong with this answer? If so, I would gladly fix it.

Comment: @user2128702 Then your compiler doesn't support the current C++ standard. You could add that crucial information to your question. I will edit my answer.

Comment: @juanchopanza How can I check what is my C++ standart?

Comment: @user2128702 Which compiler is it?

Comment: @user2128702 No idea, but I can tell you that it doesn't fully support the current standard.

Comment: @juanchopanza gcc, for example, does not enable c++11 by default. You need add the fact that c++11 is required to your answer.

Comment: @Zacrath No, I don't need to add that. It is the current standard.

Comment: @juanchopanza I am using standart DevCpp 4.9.9.2 as an IDE.

Comment: @user2128702 OMG, that is gcc 3.4.2. Next stop: http://nuwen.net/mingw.html and download gcc 4.8.2 to get all these C++11 features out of the box

Comment: @TemplateRex I did "g++ --version" in the Command prompt and it says that my GCC version is 4.6.1 I

Comment: @user2128702 Then it *might* work if you manage to set the compiler flag `-std=c++0x`.

Comment: @TemplateRex I did the gcc 4.8.2 but when I compliled my project it gives me lots of '[Linker error] undefined reference to'. Any idea why is that now ?

Comment: @user2128702 no idea, that would be another question ;-)

Answer (score 3):

If you absolutely, positively have to use C++98, you could do something like this:

```
#include <algorithm>    //copy
#include <iostream>     // cout
#include <iterator>     // iostream_iterator

void foo()
{
    int init[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int* array = new int[3]; 
    std::copy(init, init + 3, array);
    std::copy(array, array + 3, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));

    // better hope nothing bad like an exception happens in between

    delete[] array;
}

int main() 
{    
    foo();
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1fbc2a119b211228). So you define a C-array of initializers and copy them into your dynamically allocated array. The C-array `init` will be automatically deleted when `foo()` exits, but you have to manually delete `array`. The recommended way is to use `std::vector` in C++11 with an initializer-list.